# Collection Saved as asset, but I can't modify individual parts of the collection

Tags: asset-browser, asset

Basically, I have a model made up of multiple individual objects and I thought I could mark the whole collection as an asset so when I use it it is already in a neat folder and everything is there without needing to pull like 5 things, however, when I pull the collection from my asset library it is just a collection. It is all there model-wise, but I can not edit the material or the base of the model, at most I can do scale and rotation.

Answer (score 3):

Select the collection instance, hover over the 3D viewport, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and select *Make Instances Real*.

...My fault for not searching enough before asking the question.

Comment: Hello & Welcome! No harm done, clear question, clear answer, quickly resolved: Everything is fine!

Comment: But that way the parenting is not in place anymore.. I just want to copy the collection from one file to another with the neet interface of the asset browser. It should do the same thing as file->append->collection